# Generics constructor with parameter constraint?

Tags: delphi, generics

```
TMyBaseClass=class
  constructor(test:integer);
end;

TMyClass=class(TMyBaseClass);

TClass1<T: TMyBaseClass,constructor>=class()
  public
    FItem: T;
    procedure Test;
end;

procedure TClass1<T>.Test;
begin
  FItem:= T.Create;
end;

var u: TClass1<TMyClass>;
begin
  u:=TClass1<TMyClass>.Create();
  u.Test;
end;
```

How do I make it to create the class with the integer param. What is the workaround?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just typecast to the correct class:

```
type
  TMyBaseClassClass = class of TMyBaseClass;

procedure TClass1<T>.Test;
begin
  FItem:= T(TMyBaseClassClass(T).Create(42));
end;
```

Also it's probably a good idea to make the constructor virtual.

Comment: This is the best way I have seen to solve the problem. Interestingly I looked in my own code, attempted to change to this approach and realised that sometimes runtime decisions are made as to what class to create which means that the approach outlined in my answer has a use. I have therefore left that answer there in case it's useful to anyone.

Comment: @David Thanks! Do you think the final typecast from your edit: `T(...)` is necessary? I don't see why; the returned instance has to be and will be of type `T`, by definition. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: It is necessary. `TMyBaseClassClass(T).Create` returns a new instance of `TMyBaseClass`, but it needs to return `T` which is a more specialised class.

Comment: Also I think you answer would be much much stronger without the alternative. The first block of code just nails it completely. But hey, that's just my opinion.

Comment: Question: Why make the constructor virtual. I only want to learn why. Your first solution is correct. And yes the T(...) thing is necessary. I tried to do your first solution without it and got the errors in Herffernan's answer. So thank you and please do tell about virtual constructor.

Comment: @TOndrej I repeat my suggestion regarding `CreateWithValue`. I tried it and it failed with an AV. I suspect it's a compiler bug in the sense that the code is being accepted when in fact it should not be accepted. Since you (rightly) have the most upvotes, and the accept, I feel it's worth cleaning it up.

Comment: @netboy Without virtual constructor you will always get the constructor from TMyBaseClassClass. If you want to do something different in TMyClass constructor you need virtual. This answer says "it's probably a good idea". I would have said, "it is essential".

Comment: @netboy I don't know what you mean by "the errors in Heffernan's answer". The code in my answer compiles without errors. Are you saying it doesn't? Perhaps we are on different versions of Delphi if that is so.

Comment: @David: for me, `constructor CreateWithValue(Integer); virtual;` worked fine. But that leaves the inherited Create open for (ab)use. AFAICT, in all solutions TMyBasClass has a parameterless constructor that could be called erroneously outisde the generic class, either specific to the class (so you could raise a runtime error) or inherited. I don't see a way to avoid that, except making Create private (but not strict private) and putting the generic class in the same unit. Probably not what most people would want.

Comment: @Rudy I compiled on D2010 and `CreateWithValue(Integer)` gave runtime AV. What about you? XE?

Comment: FWIW, it is not quite clear to me why TClass1 should be generic at all. What am I missing?

Comment: @David: XE here. You got a runtime AV? I'll try this in D2010, if the VM with my Vista setup still works (had some problems with it).

Comment: @Rudy Documentation of constructor constraint talks about parameterless constructor. I don't see how it can be valid to call a constructor on `T` without casting unless you have the constructor constraint, but that constraint only guarantees parameterless constructor. It's making no sense to me. Do you understand the spec?

Comment: @Rudy Did you think I meant compile time AV? Have you executed code successfully on XE that called that CreateWithValue constructor?

Comment: @David: same AV here too, in D2010. But it works fine in DXE. Seems like a bug in D2010. Yup, in the CPU view it seems that it accesses a wrong value for the class, while it correctly gets it in XE. Tested this by adding a `Writeln(T.ClassName);`. That correctly prints `TMyClass`, and there I can see what the pointer to T is. It is not the same address that is accessed when `T.CeateWithValue(42)`is called.

Comment: @Rudy I don't think that code should even compile. Why should it? The constructor constraint says that new instances can be created via parameterless constructors. Why would you need the constraint just for parameterless constructors, but not for constructors with parameters? It's make zero sense to me.

Comment: The constructor constraint says that the class must have a parameterless constructor, and if it hasn't, no other constructors can be called. I can even have two public constructors, Create(Integer) and CreateWithValue(Integer), and that compiles. And yet it disallows you to call parameterless Create on a TMyClass. I am flabbergasted. Could that be a solution?

Comment: @Rudy As a TeamB insider, perhaps you could pass it on to someone at Emba who would be able to give a definitive assessment.

Comment: FWIW, **I think I found a solution that completely gets rid of the parameterless constructor and yet compiles and works (in XE)**. @David: I will certainly ask someone there if this is "as designed". I hope so.

Comment: @Rudy Having read your answer, I think we can safely rule out the "as designed" possibility!

Comment: I just found out that inside the generic class, you can call Create but not Create(42) <shudder>. I'll update my answer with a warning.

Comment: @RudyVelthius and your answer was... ?

Comment: Last eit by David was after discussions at http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/17243031

Comment: I get an AV when I try this in Delphi XE. Found another solution that I have posted. It calls the constructor as a method after is instantiated with the parameterless constructor. Seems to work fine, although I don't know (haven't tested) what will happen if TMyBaseClass has a parameterless constructor that is also called from the constructor that has the parameter. This doesn't seem part of the question, though.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

The solution offered by @TOndrej is far superior to what I wrote below, apart from one situation. If you need to take runtime decisions as to what class to create, then the approach below appears to be the optimal solution.

---

I've refreshed my memory of my own code base which also deals with this exact problem. My conclusion is that what you are attempting to achieve is impossible. I'd be delighted to be proved wrong if anyone wants to rise to the challenge.

My workaround is for the generic class to contain a field `FClass` which is of type `class of TMyBaseClass`. Then I can call my virtual constructor with `FClass.Create(...)`. I test that `FClass.InheritsFrom(T)` in an assertion. It's all depressingly non-generic.  As I said, if anyone can prove my belief wrong I will upvote, delete, and rejoice!

In your setting the workaround might look like this:

```
TMyBaseClass = class
public
  constructor Create(test:integer); virtual;
end;
TMyBaseClassClass = class of TMyBaseClass;

TMyClass = class(TMyBaseClass)
public
  constructor Create(test:integer); override;
end;

TClass1<T: TMyBaseClass> = class
private
  FMemberClass: TMyBaseClassClass;
  FItem: T;
public
  constructor Create(MemberClass: TMyBaseClassClass); overload;
  constructor Create; overload;
  procedure Test;
end;

constructor TClass1<T>.Create(MemberClass: TMyBaseClassClass);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FMemberClass := MemberClass;
  Assert(FMemberClass.InheritsFrom(T));
end;

constructor TClass1<T>.Create;
begin
  Create(TMyBaseClassClass(T));
end;

procedure TClass1<T>.Test;
begin
  FItem:= T(FMemberClass.Create(666));
end;

var 
  u: TClass1<TMyClass>;
begin
  u:=TClass1<TMyClass>.Create(TMyClass);
  u.Test;
end;
```

Another more elegant solution, if it is possible, is to use a parameterless constructor and pass in the extra information in a virtual method of `T`, perhaps called `Initialize`.

Comment: Yes i know, it's not possible in C# also. But i'm searching for a workaround here.

Comment: [DCC Error]: E2010 Incompatible types: 'TMyClass' and 'TMyBaseClass'

Comment: OK, I think I can guess what that error is about. You need to cast the result of the constuctor to T. See my code.

Comment: I can't tell what you are doing wrong. I can't see your code. My code, given above, works. Oh, I just fixed a couple of little typos, but you would have fixed them too.

Comment: +1 for creativity. Are you feeling apocalyptic because of this (or does the beast have nothing to do with the apocalypse)?

Comment: Also I do so hope that we will get interface constraints for generics at some point. Then we can truly get generic and do away with the need for (abstract) base classes.

Comment: @Marjan: there are interface constraints for generics! `TTest <T : ISomeInterface>` ... or do you mean something else?

Comment: @marjan some people like 42, I prefer 666 for my random integer value

Comment: @Smasher: Sorry, yes, something completely different. Got my brain in a twist... "Interface instantiation" comes closer with a little mix in from dependency injection without the whole sh'bang of a framework. That is being able to tell an interface: go instantiate yourself if there is somebody implementing you (or X, Y and Z) and has a constructor with this signature (which would require constructor signatures to be allowed in interfaces) and have the compiler figure out which class that is in scope meets that and throw an error if there is more than one. Well, something like that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider giving the base class an explicit method for initialization instead of using the constructor:

```
TMyBaseClass = class
public
  procedure Initialize(test : Integer); virtual;
end;  

TMyClass = class(TMyBaseClass)
public
  procedure Initialize(test : Integer); override;
end;

procedure TClass1<T>.Test;
begin
  FItem:= T.Create;
  T.Initialize(42);
end;
```

Of course this only works, if the base class and all subclasses are under your control.

Comment: +1 this is a good solution until you want to be able to create instances of `T` outside the generic class.

Comment: @David one could offer the constructor with the integer parameter in addition to the `Initialize` method.

Comment: That would still leaves clients the opportunity to call parameterless constructor and omit calling Initialize which would be an error. Of course you could defend against that internal to the class, but it would be messy. If you adopt the approach you suggest (and as I suggested at almost identical moment), then I would prefer the constructor to be private. So far as I can tell, there is no *good* solution to this problem and it's rather depressing if that is so.

Answer (score 0):

What *seems* to work in Delphi XE, is to call T.Create first, and then call the class-specific Create as a method afterwards. This is similar to Rudy Velthuis' (deleted) answer, although I don't introduce an overloaded constructor. This method also seems to work correctly if T is of TControl or classes like that, so you could construct visual controls in this fashion.

I can't test on Delphi 2010.

```
type
  TMyBaseClass = class
    FTest: Integer;
    constructor Create(test: integer);
  end;

  TMyClass = class(TMyBaseClass);

  TClass1<T: TMyBaseClass, constructor> = class
  public
    FItem: T;
    procedure Test;
  end;

constructor TMyBaseClass.Create(test: integer);
begin
  FTest := Test;
end;

procedure TClass1<T>.Test;
begin
  FItem := T.Create; // Allocation + 'dummy' constructor in TObject
  try
    TMyBaseClass(FItem).Create(42); // Call actual constructor as a method
  except
    // Normally this is done automatically when constructor fails
    FItem.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;


// Calling:
var
  o: TClass1<TMyClass>;
begin
  o := TClass1<TMyClass>.Create();
  o.Test;
  ShowMessageFmt('%d', [o.FItem.FTest]);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type
  TBase = class
    constructor Create (aParam: Integer); virtual;
  end;

  TBaseClass = class of TBase;

  TFabric = class
    class function CreateAsBase (ConcreteClass: TBaseClass; aParam: Integer): TBase;
    class function CreateMyClass<T: TBase>(aParam: Integer): T;
  end;

  TSpecial = class(TBase)
  end;

  TSuperSpecial = class(TSpecial)
    constructor Create(aParam: Integer); override;
  end;

class function TFabric.CreateAsBase(ConcreteClass: TBaseClass; aParam: Integer): TBase;
begin
  Result := ConcreteClass.Create (aParam);
end;

class function TFabric.CreateMyClass<T>(aParam: Integer): T;
begin
  Result := CreateAsBase (T, aParam) as T;
end;

// using
var
  B: TBase;
  S: TSpecial;
  SS: TSuperSpecial;
begin
  B := TFabric.CreateMyClass <TBase> (1);
  S := TFabric.CreateMyClass <TSpecial> (1);
  SS := TFabric.CreateMyClass <TSuperSpecial> (1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is pretty old, I didn't see anybody proposing a simpler answer, so here goes my contribution.

Make sure your constructor is virtual. There's no need to typecast.

```
TMyBaseClass = class
public
  constructor Create(test:integer); virtual;
end;

procedure TClass1<T>.Test;
type
  TMyType = type of T;
begin
  FItem:= TMyType.Create(42);
end;
```