# Generics using constructor with overload?

Tags: delphi, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generics constructor with parameter constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215692/generics-constructor-with-parameter-constraint)

In my venture into Generics, I've now come to a dead end where I hope someone can point me to the hidden door :-)

Given this type

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    FMyString: String;
    FMyStringList: TStringList;
    procedure SetMyString(const Value: String);
    procedure SetMyStringList(const Value: TStringList);
  public
    constructor Create; overload;
    constructor Create(InitString : String); overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property MyString: String read FMyString write SetMyString;
    property MyStringList : TStringList read FMyStringList write SetMyStringList;
  end;

  TMyClassList<T:TMyClass, constructor> = class(TObjectList<T>)
  public
    constructor Create; overload;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyClass }

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  MyString := '';
  MyStringList := TStringList.Create;
  MyStringList.Add('This');
  MyStringList.Add('is');
  MyStringList.Add('a');
  MyStringList.Add('test.');
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create(InitString: String);
begin
  Create;
  MyString := InitString;
end;
```

I would like to be able to use both TMyClass constructors as needed.

```
constructor TMyClassList<T>.Create;
begin
  Add(T.Create);
//  Add(T.Create('test')); // <--- THIS FAILS ????
end;
```

But only the one without parameters is usable.

I forgot to mention - It does NOT fail ... It will not COMPILE !!

Why is that?

Regards
Bimmer_R

Comment: Correct - this one is very similar to the one you point out. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify general constructor constraints on generic types. All you can do is specify that they have a single parameterless constructor, as you have done. Work around it like this:

```
TMyClassList<T: TMyClass> = class(TObjectList<T>)
//no need for constructor constraint
...
type
  TMyClassClass = class of TMyClass;
...
constructor TMyClassList<T>.Create;
begin
  Add(TMyClassClass(T).Create('test'));
end;
```

You'll want to use a virtual constructor on `TMyClass` to make this work as you intend.

```
TMyClass = class
  constructor Create(InitString : String); virtual;
end;
```

The other option is to use a parameterless constructor and use a separate routine for initialization.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning :-). But to understand it correctly.
Even that I'm using a Class constraint
`TMyClassList<T: TMyClass>`
I still have to cast it to TMyClass .. thats kinda double up .. if you know what I mean :-)?

Comment: @David: if I try "Add(TMyClass(T).Create('test'))" I get an access violation (in Delphi XE2). This is why I used TMyClassClass(T) instead. Are we doing things differently?

Comment: Yes : Sorry - Forgot that I'm currently in XE.

Comment: @Ville You are quite right. My mistake.

Comment: Hmmm... I think I'm having a déjà vu. This solution was mentioned somewhere in an older posting I've seen. I just don't remember where.

Comment: That would be interesting to see. I did quite a few searches without finding all the answers .. atleast not the answers I'm looking for :-)
Please post anything you think has relevance to the subject.

Comment: @Rudy I remember it too. I had an answer in that Q. I can't find it either.

Comment: @Rudy it was here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215692/generics-constructor-with-parameter-constraint/7216602#7216602

Comment: Just read through that one - and it looks pretty much like this one.
This one just upped the ante with polymorphism a bit :-)

Comment: @bimmer no, polymorphism is always needed here and is discussed in the other Q.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry - you are absolutely correct. 
Since I can use every bit of information here - I would like to accept both David and Ville's answers. Can I do that by pressing V for each? Otherwise i feel like someone gets cheated.

Comment: @Bimmer You can't do that. You have to accept one. What you can do is upvote. I see that you have not yet voted. Click the up pointing triangle next to an answer that you found helpful.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually I have upvoted for both - a while back. But could not decide on which answer was more usefull. But I'll have to go for your answer then, despite the fact that Ville actually corrected you, but you have given me som extra time in your .... :-)

Comment: @Smasher: That was the one I was thinking of, indeed.

Answer (score 4):

I got it working like this:

```
type
  TMyClassClass = class of TMyClass;

...

constructor TMyClassList<T>.Create;
begin
  Add(T.Create);
  Add(TMyClassClass(T).Create('test'));
end;

...

var
  Test : TMyClassList<TMyClass>;
begin
  Test := TMyClassList<TMyClass>.Create;
end;
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. What happens when we throw plymorphism into this one?
Say we derive from TMyClass and TMyClassList like 
`TOurClass = class(TMyClass)

TOurClassList<T:TOurClass> = class(TMyClassList<TMyClass>)

`
Can we somehow achieve true polymorphism on the constructor for TOurClass when creating TOurClassList ??

Hope you can follow me here :-)

Comment: @Bimmer_R You need a virtual constructor like in my (now corrected) answer.  Also +1 for getting it right where I did not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thx. But removing the constructor constraint will leave me with no choice but to cast to TMyClassClass for both me Creates ... right? Actually I can live with that - I'm just looking for _one correct way._ 
In my question (in the comment above) I speculate into applying polymorphism to this. 
Actually I think that I might be off on the wrong foot .. or am I?

Any advice on how to do it?

Comment: @Bimmer_R Why do you want multiple constructors? Keep the constructor constraint if you want. I explained in my answer that you need to use virtual constructors here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm rewriting a rather big library which allready implements several different constructors. Mainly for quick initializing, but also to decide how to construct the instance.
ie. we could provide a TSQLConnection to one of our Objects in the constructor - and by doing that the constructor knows that a great deal more has to be initialized (datasnap / database and so on).