# Why this code won't compile in XE3

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe3

```pas
type
  TForm72 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }    
  end;

  TTestForm = class(TForm)
  public
    constructor CreateTest(AOwner: TComponent); virtual;
  end;

  TTestForm1 = class(TTestForm)    
  public
    constructor CreateTest(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TTest<T: TTestForm, constructor> = class(TObject)
  public
    class procedure Test;
  end;

var
  Form72: TForm72;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm72.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TTest<TTestForm1>.Test;
end;

{ TTest<T> }

class procedure TTest<T>.Test;
var
  F: T;
begin
  F := T.CreateTest(Application);
  Form72.Caption :=  F.Name;
end;

{ TTestForm }

constructor TTestForm.CreateTest(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;

{ TTestForm1 }

constructor TTestForm1.CreateTest(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Caption := 'Bang';
end;

end.
```

This code compiled in XE2, but fail with "[dcc32 Error] Unit71.pas(55): E2010 Incompatible types: 'T' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'"  in XE3. What I did wrong, or compiler did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact this code highlights a compiler bug in XE2. In XE2, the code compiles when it should not. Remove the `constructor` constraint and the compilation fails with

```
E2568 Can't create new instance without CONSTRUCTOR constraint in type 
parameter declaration
```

But the `constructor` constraint merely states that the class has a parameterless constructor. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Constraints_in_Generics#Constructor_Constraints) states:

> **Constructor Constraints**
>
> A type parameter may be constrained by zero or one instance of the
>   reserved word "constructor". This means that the actual argument type
>   must be a class that defines a default constructor (a public
>   parameterless constructor), so that methods within the generic type
>   may construct instances of the argument type using the argument type's
>   default constructor, without knowing anything about the argument type
>   itself (no minimum base type requirements).

The fact that the presence or otherwise of the `constructor` constraint influences this code indicates that the XE2 compiler has a fault.

---

In XE3 the code correctly fails to compile. The only way to call a constructor with the syntax `T.Create` is if you are using a `constructor` constraint and are calling a parameterless constructor. That is not the case here and so XE3 correctly reports a compilation error.

You need some casting to make it compile.

```
F := T(TTestForm(T).CreateTest(Application));
```

This is a [well-known trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215692/generics-constructor-with-parameter-constraint) to get around some of the quirks of the Delphi generics implementation's handling of constructors. Although it looks messy, I believe that this code is what the language designers intended us to use. In my opinion, the change in behaviour is due to a bug fix and XE3 is behaving as designed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I face progress. With your correction it's have compile. But fail on run with access violation.

Comment: Sorry. I had been not well focused reader. In fact F := T(TTestFormClass(T).CreateTest(Application)); work well

Comment: Done.As remark - this type casting exercise looks ugly. In idea generics invented to avoiding type casting, not for upcount.

Comment: @user1723322 I agree. Object construction is a bit of a special case though. I think the designers could have done more to make such code less, well, yucky.

Comment: The link to *well-known trick* states: *Alternatively, name your constructor something else than Create.* Isn't it exactly what topic-starter made in `T.CreateTest(Application)` ? Or did TOndrej meant somethign different ?

Comment: @Arioch'The Naming the constructor to something other than `Create` doesn't help at all. I fixed the other answer. I believe that `TOndrej` answered that away from a compiler. Because I've now fixed two compilation errors in that answer!

Comment: And that looks really like a bug in XE3. Why should compiler care about default constructor at all if i eplicitly call constructor and if class restriction is in place ? why should Delphi care about that constructor unless i have a member variable (which is not ni the example) ?

Comment: @Arioch'The It is as designed. The documentation is clear. I don't understand why the designers chose to require the `TTestForm(T)` cast, but it's easy to see why the other cast is necessary. I cannot understand why the designers included the `constructor` constraint. It doesn't really help much. But I don't think it's a bug as such. Just a poor design.

Comment: Given .CreateTest is virtual - no, i don't understand why `TTestForm(T)` was required and why that is not bug. Especially since TClass is VMT pointer. Well, Delphi lacks co- and contravariance and probably just cannot have clean mixing of generics and inheritance :-(  BTW, what is the Delphi way (except RTTI) to call that "default constructor" w/o knowing the name ? New procedure does not work with TClass

Comment: @Arioch'The Calling a constructor is different from calling a method. Even if the syntax looks the same, there's a lot more going on. So I can see why it needs different treatment. But I'd have hoped that the designers would have kept that on their side of the fence. As for the constructor constraint, and what the name of the constructor is, I don't know those details. I never use constructor constraints. They seem useless to me.

Comment: @David but type restriction already conveys that `.CreateTest` was a constructor. And Delphi does not have C object init syntax w/o constructor name. I just cannot see any Delphi usecase for it at all.